# running spark-shell makes a "connection refused"

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, spark-shell

I am trying to run spark over hadoop(yarn).
when I try to run spark-shell it makes ConnectionRefused exception.the log is like this:

```
ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: The YARN application has already ended! It might have been
killed or the Application Master may have failed to start. Check the YARN application logs for more details.
19/10/22 15:13:36 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1571690458300_0002 failed 2 times due to
 Error launching appattempt_1571690458300_0002_000002. Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: 
Call From master/x.x.x.x(a correct IP:) ) to ubuntu:43856 failed on connection exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop
/ConnectionRefused
```

but when I run wordcount example with yarn every thing is ok.(so the yarn is ok, I think)
as the log said it's try to connect to ubuntu:43856, I think it's try to connect to one of my slaves
that it should be slave1:43856(as I set the the workers file). and I think the problem is here but
running yarn alone(without spark) is ok.
and the export of `yarn node -list` command is :

```
         Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       Number-of-Running-Containers
    ubuntu:43856                RUNNING       ubuntu:8042                                  0
    ubuntu:37951                RUNNING       ubuntu:8042                                  0
    ubuntu:34335                RUNNING       ubuntu:8042                                  0
    ubuntu:46500                RUNNING       ubuntu:8042                                  0
```

there are a lot config files, let me know if one(or more) of that files needed.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Does ping from master to slaves work fine? Maybe there is an issue with your network

Comment: yes,that's fine.as I said the yarn run wordcount so I think everything should be ok

Comment: but I think the `Node-Http-Address` should be : `slave1:8042`, `slave2:8042`, `slave3:8042`, `slave4:8042`(I don't know this guess is right or not)